# How can I get ISO-based language string from FileVersionInfo?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, vb.net-2010

I have a windows form in VB.net 2010 which needs to read remote .exe's language string.

Usually, this could be done via

```
oFileInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo("path to .exe here")
Dim sMyLanguage = oFileInfo.Language
```

Unfortunately, this will return something like "englisch", "französisch" on a German Windows which is absolutely useless for me.

The best would be an ISO-based code, like EN, DE, FR, etc. Another unique identifier like a codepage number or something similar would also be okay.

System.Globalization also doesn't seem to have kind of a mapping of language strings to something useful.

Any idea how to get such a language identification de-coupled from the language of my operating system? Currently, my idea is to use a .csv file with three gazillions of translations which doesn't sound to be appropriate.

Comment: Another idea is somehow to access the remote .exe's resource table (like with tools as ResourceHacker, ResEdit, Restorator etc.), but it seems that .NET has no 'built-in' way to access foreign resources. Using My.Resources is not really helpful with this.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a solution:

In System.Globalization, there is not quite a direct mapping, but as in https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.lcid(v=vs.110).aspx there are just about 140 languages listed, so I made a .csv file with Culture ID  and to returning string and looped thru it with a simple For loop.

```
    For i = 1 To gsLanguages.Count - 1
        Try
            oLang = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo(CInt(gsLanguages(i).Split(";")(1)), True)

            If oLang.DisplayName.ToLower.StartsWith(sLangString) Then
                sLanguage = gsLanguages(i).Split(";")(0)
                Exit For
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    Next
```

No question, this may not be the best solution. But in my testing, it had a very high chance to hit, so this is good enough for me.